# How to concatenate char and string on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, string

I want to add some marks to separate some strings. 
How to add a char to a string?

e.g. add '\x01' to "Hello", add '\x02' before "World" and add '\x03' after "World".

So I can create a string "\x01 Hello \x02 World \x03" which has some separate marks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to modify a string, you have to use `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString`. There is no such need if you want to create a string from scratch.

For instance, you may want to use `+stringWithFormat:` method:

```
NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c %@ %c %@ %c",
                                                 0x01,
                                                 @"Hello",
                                                 0x02,
                                                 @"World",
                                                 0x03];
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm..

You could do something like this:

```
NSString *hello = @"hello";
char ch [] = {'\x01'};
hello = [hello stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)ch]];
```

I make a a char* to append out of your single char and use stringWithUTF8String to add it.

There's probably a less long-winded way of solving it however!

Nick.

Comment: `stringWithUTF8String` expects a null-terminated string, I believe, which is not what we have here.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you're asking... But would stringWithFormat maybe help you?

E.g,

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@%c%@%c", 1, @"hello", 2, @"world", 3];
```